# How to run babel-node in deattach mode

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, babel-node

I follow this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/react-on-the-server-for-beginners-build-a-universal-react-and-node-app).

It uses `NODE_ENV=production node_modules/.bin/babel-node --presets 'react,es2015' src/server.js`

My **1st** question is:

How to I run the command line above in deattach mode? i.e. the command line above doesn't allow me to quit the terminal.

My **2nd** question is:

However, from the docs (https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/..., it is said that you shouldn't use babel-node in production, as it is very heavy. So what is the proper way tot run the server?